# Angular 1.5.8 - Error: [$sce:unsafe] on google maps url

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps, typescript

I am getting the above error when trying to display a google map

**View**

```
<div class="main" ng-repeat="item in Ctrl.Opportunities.PagedData.Results">                   
    <div class="pull-right" id="GoogleMaps" ng-show="Ctrl.GetSafeUrl('https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q={{item.PostCode}}&key=mykey')" />
        <!--////// Simple Embeded API Using PostCode //////////--> 
        <iframe width="200" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0" ng-src="{{Ctrl.SafeURL}}"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller** - Using Typescript

```
class OpportunityListController extends BaseEmployedController {
    static controllerId = 'opportunityListController';
    static $inject = [ '$http', '$sce', OpportunityService.serviceId
    ];

    public Opportunities: O.Employed.OpportunityListResult;
    public MapsURL: string = "";
    private SafeURL: string = "";

  constructor(protected $modal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService,
        protected $http: ng.IHttpService,
        private $sce: ng.ISCEService,
        private OpportunityService: OpportunityService,
    ) {

      this.Opportunities = new O.Employed.OpportunityListResult();  
  }

  public GetSafeUrl(Url: string) {
    if (Url) {
       this.SafeURL = this.$sce.getTrustedUrl(Url);
     }
    return this.SafeURL;
    }
}
```

Am using the method GetSafeUrl() since previously I was getting an $interpolate:noconcat error

**Update**

I attempted to implement the suggestions provided by Niels as such:

Changed my url assignment to `this.$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(Url);` but the items failed to load and I received a 414 Request-URI Too Large

I added Content-Security-Policy meta tag to my _Layout.cshtml but get various errors

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-ZDjCdTstFUpLDovBdF6MXbSPB35alPr6sy4CYtyHSA4='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

plus the same *"$sce:unsafe"* error

However, I think where I've gone wrong is in the way that I am using the method below, which was still in angular.js.

**SceDeleagateProvider**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
     // Allow same origin resource loads.
     'self',
     // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
    'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place**'
    ]);
```

Instead I've attempted to inject `"$sceDelegateProvider"` into my controller and assign it's value as
`private $sceDelegateProvider: ng.ISCEDelegateProvider`, in the controllers constructor

I have then created the following method

```
 public SetSCEDelegateProvider($sceDelegateProvider) {
        this.$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(["self",
            "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place**"
        ]);
    }
```

This still doesn't work either though.

How should I correctly be implementing the $sceDelegateProvider service?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
this.$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(Url);
```

Otherwise you maybe have to add the Content-Security-Policy meta tag in index.html. Something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src *;
    font-src 'self' data: http://*.gstatic.com;
    script-src 'self' http://*.googleapis.com;
    style-src 'self' blob: http://*.googleapis.com;
    media-src * 'self' data:;
    img-src 'self' data: http://*.gstatic.com http://*.googleapis.com
">
```

Comment: thanks Niels, where is the src argument coming from? is this the same as the url argument I have?

Comment: @HitTheSky Yes, just made a change. It's the same Url as yours.

Comment: thanks, I've attempted your suggestions and updated accordingly.